# Send email with contents of channel form upon submission

Tags: channel-form, email

I want to have a channel form (new version of SAEF) form on my website for users to fill out. Upon submission I want the form to obviously save as an entry in the system (which is what it does by default) but ALSO send the contents of the filled-out form in an email to a specified email address.

Is this possible either natively, via an addon, or possibly via a hook and writing an addon?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

[MX Notify Control](http://www.eec.ms/add-ons/mx-notify-control) (free) or [Postmaster](https://objectivehtml.com/postmaster) (paid) can do this using the 'new entry create' hook.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your situation you can also use a workflow module that alerts an admin of publish & edits by sending an email. There is [Publisher Lite](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/publisher-lite) (the [full version](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/publisher) supports translations too) and [Better Workflow](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/better-workflow).